# Pass input text into URL to render new iframe on page

Tags: javascript

I'd like to pass text entered into an input box into the middle of a URL that would render an embedded iframe based on whatever the user "searched." Spaces between words will have to automatically be converted into "%20" or "+".

See here for an example of what I'd like to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/pw3fL453/

```
Enter a keyword or phrase into the box below to see if it's trending.
<br>
<input placeholder="***input***"></input>

<iframe src="http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?hl=en-US&q=***INPUT***&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=500&h=300"></iframe>
```

Comment: What is your actual question? What have you tried so far? You are talking about what you would like, nowhere i see this is my problem and this is causing the problem. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a explanation on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var timeout;
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');

input.addEventListener('input', function(e){
    if(timeout !== undefined)
      clearTimeout(timeout);
  
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
      iframe.src = 'http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?hl=en-US&q='+ input.value +'&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=500&h=300';
      }, 1000);
});
```

```css
iframe{
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
}

input{
    margin:40px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="***input***"></input>

<iframe src="http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?hl=en-US&q=***INPUT***&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=500&h=300"></iframe>
```

It might be better to just have a button though, the input event will fire every time you do a change on the input box.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      iframe.src = 'http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?hl=en-US&q='+ input.value +'&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=500&h=300';
});
```

```css
iframe{
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
}

input{
    margin:40px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="***input***"></input><button>go</button>

<iframe src="http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?hl=en-US&q=***INPUT***&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=500&h=300"></iframe>
```

Comment: FWIW, there is nothing in this example that couldn't be done as easily without jQuery.

Comment: Yes, I realize that. I just thought on `jQuery` right from the start. I'll make it vanilla JS.

Comment: Is there any way you could write this up to show how the button would work? I think you are correct that that would be better from a UX standpoint.

Comment: @MichaelMacfadden, i added an example with a button. But I really suggest you reading on some javascript.